# Stop further event handlers on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm writing a little jQuery extension that prevents a user from double clicking on a link.

```
$.fn.preventDoubleClick = function() {
    return this.click(function() {
        var $t = $(this)
            , retVal = $t.data('active')  // check the internal flag
        ;
        if (retVal || retVal === undefined) { // if ON...
            $t.data('active', false);  // set the internal flag to OFF
            setTimeout(function() {
                $t.data('active', true);
            }, 1000);  // after 1 second, set the internal flag to ON
            console.log("allowed");
            return true;
        } else {  // if OFF...
            console.log("blocked");
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

the problem is that if there are other click event handlers on the elements, they still fire:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
});
$('#myLink').preventDoubleClick();
```

And now when you double click the link, I get this in my log:

> allowed
>   clicked
>   blocked
>   clicked

So basically, I need the click function inside `preventDoubleClick` to stop all the other event handlers from firing. How can I do this?

Comment: Also, "preventDoubleClick" is a misleading name, afterall it's not prevented -the user still double clicks - you just block it from firing the event, I think...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Thanks to Adam's link, I was able to see the function I needed: [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/).

Comment: This also works without jQuery, here's the documentation for the standard [stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopImmediatePropagation)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for [event.stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Types/Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

EDIT: turns out this was not the correct option for Nick's purposes.  Please see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746506/stop-further-event-handlers-on-an-element/746533#746533).

Comment: The documentation on that page says "Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running."

Comment: Yes very true, glad the link was helpful anyway =)