# Add a new event handler to run first

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've just been working on a jQuery extension [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746506/stop-further-event-handlers-on-an-element), and have now run into another problem: I need to make sure that my particular event handler runs before any other event handlers which may already be on an element.

When adding events, it appears as though they get pushed to the back of a queue, whereas I really need mine to be at the front, such that it can prevent other ones from running. How can you do this?

Comment: Hi again Nick, please check if this is what you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll find something useful [here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/da7ee3f9c17db398/10e8cff28d3e31b5?lnk=raot) (jquery google groups)
but from what I've read there is no "easy-to-use" function to work with the events stack

EDIT: there was also a link to [this plugin](http://snipplr.com/view/13556/jquery-event-stack-binder/) there. It's called event stack binder.