# Return confirm still executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following for a delete button and although I get the confirm message, if I click cancel it still goes through with it:

```
<a onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')" class="btn btn-default btn-sm deleteList" href="#" list_id="1467" title="Delete your list: listName">Delete</a>
```

Anything obvious?

UPDATE:

This is attached to a jquery click function, so if the cancel stops the link following through, how can I prevent the click handler from firing?

**UPDATE 2**

Also tried at start of click handler but same problem:

```
$('.deleteList').on('click', function(e) {
        confirm('are you sure?');
        var list_id = $(this).attr("list_id");
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajax/actions/deleteList.php?listId=' + list_id,
            success: function (data) {
                    var d = $.now();
                    window.location.href = "/pages/dashboard?listDelete=" + d + "#mylists";
            }
        }); // End .ajax
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: If you hit cancel, it won't go through to `#` which is the default action as per your link's `href`. But if you have other click handlers attached, they will be executed.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah it calls a JQuery click function - how can I prevent that?

Comment: `confirm()` at the start of the actual click handler itself.

Comment: `event.preventdefault()`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney [`e.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: @digitalextremist did you saw the time, hardly mili seconds far

Comment: @digitalextremist already got that, I didn;t think that was there for that though

Comment: Because it's not. `event.stopPropagation()` at best, but that doesn't help if the delete handler is called first.

Comment: You actually want `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop further event handlers on an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746506/stop-further-event-handlers-on-an-element)

Comment: Added `jQuery` tag since `jQuery` is being used in the question.

Comment: This is now an incorrect use of `confirm()` and a problem with `.ajax()` being asynchronous.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You should edit your question back to its original state, then submit a new question as the entire focus of your question has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fool-proof answer:

```
$('.deleteList').on('click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //de Added by @crush
    return confirm("are you sure?")
})
```

Then remove `onclick="..."`.

As of the updated question, the entire question is different. The issue is now an invalid use of `confirm()` and a possible asynchronous problem with `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Relevant API link: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Comment: Thats stops the whole click handler working

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It's now unclear what your intended outcome is.